# Stationary distribution vs invariant distribution of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Lets $p$ be a distribution on a finite sample space with $n$ points. I wish to find a transition matrix that is invariant with respect to $p$, that is
$$p^T T = p^T$$.

The problem is clearly underspecified since the number of variables ($n^2$) will always be greater (except when $n=2$) than the number of constraints ($2n$).

I was wondering if there any way to characterize the subset of solutions that have $p$ as the stationary distribution as well (and not just invariant with respect to $p$).

Comment: One of the well-known property is the reversibility of Markov chain. Are you looking for something like this to further classify the Markov chain with the same stationary distribution?

Comment: Will restricting to reversible Markov chains, give a unique invariant distribution? 

I was wondering if anyone has characterized the solution space of Markov chains with $p$ as stationary distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Markov chain with a finite state space has a unique stationary distribution if and only if it has exactly one closed communicating class; see e.g. [these notes](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~ejm/M3S4/NOTES3.pdf) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Steady-state_analysis_and_limiting_distributions).

Comment: That wasn't my question. Given a distribution,  how can we characterize the space of Markov chains for which it is stationary.

Comment: The uniqueness property that you mention is quite well known and obvious

Comment: @user2808118: Well, people have been known to ask obvious things here, you know? :-)

Comment: Right. I tend to do that all the time :-)

Comment: @user2808118: I'm afraid I still don't understand what you're asking. Why does "$T$ satisfies $p^\top T=p^\top$ and has exactly one closed communicating class" not characterise the space of Markov chains for which $p$ is the unique stationary distribution? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how you're using the terms "stationary" and "invariant"?

Comment: Ohh.. Right... How did I miss that.  Thanks.   My previous reply is true.  I do tend to ask obvious questions.